# How to control the transparency of the center of the object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

Here is the material of the object and the object however when I look through it other objects appears, they should not be visible, this happens because the transparency blending has to be high enough so that the edges look like a fading blue.
[image: Material and object and What I'd like to make it look like.]

I'd also like that the border that are fading off are transparent, that's why I'm using a transparent BSDF.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: User a *Color Ramp* node after the output of *Layer Weight* to control transparency progression

Comment: Thanks it works, however, isn't there a more fine-way to tune the control of transparency, I guess other than transparency textures no right?

Comment: Well that method is actually driving the progression between emission and transparency. To directly control transparency you can use a similar setup as color input in the *Transparency* node